# how to parse the contents of a particular row of a html table into array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html-parsing

I need to pass a one of these row contents of features-table to an array. But the problem is I used an iframe to display the table. And I need it to happen when after clicking the image of particular row.

**In main.php**

```
<iframe id="ifrm" src="reserved_tables/reserved_rooms_table.php"></iframe>
```

**In reserved_rooms_table.php**

```
    <?php

include '../core/init.php';

$username = $user_data['username']; 

$que = "SELECT * FROM ordered_rooms WHERE `username` LIKE '$username'"; 
$reslt = mysql_query($que);

echo '<table class="features-table"  >'; 

echo '<thead>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Date</td>
                <td>Start At</td>
                <td>End At</td>
                <td>Action</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($reslt)){   
echo '<tr><td>' . $row['room_name'] .'  </td><td> '. $row['date'] . '</td><td>'. $row['s_at'].'hrs</td>
      <td>'. $row['e_at'].'hrs</td><td><input type="image" src="../images/cross.png" onclick="delete();" value=""></td></tr>'; 
}

echo "</tbody></table>"; 

mysql_close(); //connection closed
```

?>

Comment: Fetch the data from reserved_rooms_table.php instead of main.php, and use an HTML parser.

Comment: I just need to remove one of these rows from the database by clicking a cross image. for that I need to get contents of that particular row into an array.

Comment: You don't need to parse the row for this. Just create <a href="action" with id of the row you want to delete, and delete it via script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't entirely clear what you're trying to do.  If you want to take data from an HTML table row and send it to a PHP array after a click then you'll need to use javascript.

Keep it simple.  Create a link that sends the data to whatever URL/file does the processing:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($reslt)) {   
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['room_name'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['date'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['s_at'] ?>hrs</td>
        <td><?php echo $row['e_at'] ?>hrs</td>
        <td><a id="my_link" href="some_file.php?room_name=<?php echo $row['room_name'] ?>&date=<?php echo $row['date'] ?>&s_at=<?php echo $row['s_at'] ?>&e_at=<?php echo $row['e_at'] ?>"><input type="image" src="../images/cross.png" value=""><a/></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
```

The data will then be available to some_file.php in $_GET.

Note that you can still use javascript to process this dynamically.  You could add a click function to the link, so that when it is clicked, it does an AJAX call using the href value.  For example:

```
$('#my_link').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href
    });
});
```

Comment: I just need to remove one of these rows from the database by clicking a cross image. for that I need to get contents of that particular row into an array.